# Multiple tables with same name in Postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a very large database and if I look in the pg_stat_user_tables I can see that the same table is linked to public schema and then what seems to be 'system' generated schemas. Why is this happening and is it a problem?

```
schemaname       | relname
-----------------+--------
public           | chatter  
camunxudb018263  | chatter  
camunxudb0117140 | chatter
```

Comment: Those aren't "system generated" schemas. Somebody ran `CREATE SCHEMA camunxudb018263;` and created the table there.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.